# Product Type in Coq

Tags: coq, cartesian-product

I'm having trouble passing a parameter to a product type in coq. I have a definition that looks like,

```
    Definition bar (a:Type) := a->Type.
```

I need to define a function that takes in 'a' and the thing made by 'bar a' and outputs their product/ordered pair. So I tried the following.

```
    Definition foo (a:Type)(b:bar a):= prod a b.
```

Which gives me the error

> The term "b" has type "bar a" while it is expected to have type "Type".

What's really confusing here is that this,

```
    Definition foo (a:Type) := prod a (bar a).
```

works just fine. Clearly 'bar a' has type 'Type', so I'm not sure how to fix my original definition. I suspect I'm not passing variables properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see an error, expand `bar a` in your `foo` definition:

```
Definition foo (a:Type)(b:a->Type):= prod a b.
```

Now it should be clear that `b` is not a type, it is a function from `a` to `Type`.

And as you never get an object of type `a`, you can't apply `b` to anything, and can't get a `Type` from it.

For the second definition, expand again to see why it works:

```
Definition foo (a:Type) := prod a (a->Type).
```

Both `a` and `a->Type` are valid `Type`'s for a product.

Comment: I see. Thanks a bunch.